# Is it possible to pass data to app.js in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to pass data to app.js in Laravel?
I need to pass the value of Session::getId() to app.js since I create a websocket in that file. I know it is possible to get the CSRF-TOKEN like so:

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
```

but I need the session ID.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: @linuxartisan : That only works in `.blade.php` templates, not `.js` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned CSRF token works because you have a meta tag in your layout.

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Not sure of the security implications of exposing the session id, but you could theoretically do the same.

```html
<meta name="session-id" content="{{ session()->getId() }}">
```

```js
$('meta[name="session-id"]').attr('content');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from cookie. The cookie name of session id in Laravel it is laravel_session.

```
    function getCookie(name) {

        var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
          "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
))
return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined
 }
var session_id = getCookie('laravel_session');
```

Comment: nope, laravel encryptes all cookies. see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests#cookies

Comment: Ok, but adding session id into metatag is very danger because all of third party scripts connected to page from other domains will have access to session id and it is mean that it is possible to login like a user just passing this session id into cookie! You should never do this!